# Cyanogenmod 9 stuck in boot loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop

Let me start off by saying that I have a Verizon Galaxy Nexus.

I flashed cyanogenmod 10.1 last night and was having some issues so I decided to go back to 9.  Unfortunately clockworkmod wasn't able to use my recovery data due to the new profile feature in Android 4.2.2.  So instead, I flashed CyanogenMod 9 once again.  Not when I boot it, it just stays on the blue loading screen.  I can't even get to recovery mode because when I boot in Odin I get the message "Downloading... do not turn off target"

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get into fastboot mode (which bypasses the download mode you are currently in) by pressing and holding the Volume Up and Down buttons while turning on the phone. This should get you into fastboot. From there, you can enter recovery by pressing volume up twice and power to confirm

Once you are in recovery, you will need to perform a Factory Reset/Data Wipe.

If your recovery somehow got hosed, you can download the recovery image from CM's wiki page and then get into fastboot mode and use fastboot to flash the recovery.

```
fastboot flash recovery "c:\location\to\recovery.img"
```